# Turning n (k,k) arrays into (k,k,n) array

Tags: numpy

Let's says I have 4 5x5 numpy arrays.  I need to make them a 5x5x4 numpy array.  Putting them in a list and numpying that list makes them a 4x5x5 array.  So I guess I need each element to be an array of their given x,y elements.  Which I could brute force in Python but I have a feeling I'm just missing some numpy builtin which is much faster.

```
target = np.zeros((3, 3, 4))
arrays = []

for i in range(4):
    arrays.append(np.zeros((3, 3)))

new_array = []
for y in range(3):
    row = []
    for x in range(3):
        item = []
        for a in range(4):
            item.append(arrays[a][x][y])
        row.append(item)
    new_array.append(row)
final = np.array(new_array)

if final == target:
    print("You've got it")
else:
    print("Not yet, ", final, target)
```

Comment: please give a reproducible example and the expected output (make your arrays non ambiguous and you wan also decrease the size to something smaller like 3x3). I believe you want `np.dstack(list_of_arrays)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `np.stack` with `axis=-1` param.

```
l = [np.random.randint(0,5,(5,5)) for i in range(4)] # 4 5x5 numpy arrays

output = np.stack(l,-1)  #<-----
output.shape
```

```
(5, 5, 4)
```

This is the same if you take an array, use `np.stack` and then `transpose` or `swapaxis`.

```
arr = np.stack(l)              #shape 4,5,5
output1 = arr.transpose(2,1,0) #axis order 2,1,0

(output == output1).all()
```

```
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the nested for loops, you could use `np.swapaxes()`:

`final = np.swapaxes(arrays, 0, 2)`

More generally you could use `np.stack()`:

```
tmp = [np.random.randn(4, 4) for x in range(5)]
np.stack(tmp, axis=-1)
```

Comment: Hey @thijs, I have already covered the `np.stack` with `axis=-1` in my solution. better to avoid redundancy. thanks!